# Trying to use Kabsch algorithm but keep getting this error

Tags: c++, class

This is my code:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Geometry>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

  Eigen::Matrix3Xd in(3, 100, 100), out(30, 100, 0);    
  Eigen::Affine3d A;

  A = Find3DAffineTransform(in,out);

  return 0;
}
```

and I am using the functions provided by wiki:

https://github.com/oleg-alexandrov/projects/blob/master/eigen/Kabsch.cpp#L4

Basically, I was trying to get the rotation matrix based on the input and output points given.

And this the error I got:

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The most meaningful error message is the first one, while your screenshot shows the latter. **Always** look at the first error message.

Comment: And always post errors and code here as text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code it does not seem that you are actually *using* this code from github.

You should either copy-paste the contents of `Kabsch.cpp` to your application above `main` (this is a quick'n'dirty solution), or you should:

1. Add Kabsch.cpp to your build (meaning it should be compiled and linked with your `main` file
2. Forward declare `Find3DAffineTransform` function above your `main` (or put the declaration in a separate hpp file and include it from your `main` file